# How to create a value in enum with '&'

Tags: c#, regex

I need to create a enum value something like this' DESIGN & BUILD'. I am writing an importer service and that imports the types like above. I need to compare it with ones in the Db.

Is it possible to create enum values like above? Moreover, I think we could also do it by taking a regex expression that yields only text but not any sort of symbols, I mean we only get 'DESIGNBUILD'.

Comment: The question is hard to understand. You want to generate C# enum code? Do you want `DESIGN & BUILD` to yield a `DESIGN` value and a `BUILD` value, or one `DESIGNBUILD` value? What does it look like in context? Can you give us some sample inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. Enum value names have to be valid C# identifiers, and that excludes `&`. I suggest you use `DescriptionAttribute` or something similar to provide more flexible metadata for the enum values.

While you *could* use a regular expression to perform the mapping, I believe you'll end up with a more flexible result if you use metadata. You can then easily build a `Dictionary<string, YourAttributeType>` and vice versa.

Comment: Hi ., I know that a description Attribute is useful but he rest of the importer code wil not follow this so I need to change the whole code in order to get on with this, can we come up with a better solution please

Comment: Dictionary is what I would do in such a case. :)

Comment: @manasareddy.kundur: Introduce a single point which performs the mapping between text and enum values. It's then an implementation decision. If you've got a *lot* of code which already assumes a direct mapping between text and enum value names (e.g. using Enum.Parse everywhere) that's simply an unfortunate design mistake which you'll have to rectify. The regex approach wouldn't make that any easier.